# Algebraic number to Liouville number

Tags: transcendental-numbers, liouville-numbers

If $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0,1\right\}$ is an algebraic number, can $\ln\left(a\right)$ ever be a Liouville number?

This is not a homework question, nor do I know much about the innards of proving these kinds of things. I am just very interested in transcendental numbers.

Comment: $\ln(a)$ is known to be transcendental for $a$ algebraic, and of course Liouville numbers are known to be transcendental. Combined with the continuity of $\ln(x)$ over $\Bbb R^+$ and that the Liouville numbers form a dense, uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$, I feel like the answer is "probably." Granted this is mostly handwaving and is far from anything resembling a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly it can't, but I would be surprised if this were provable in the current state of the art, even in the case where $a$ is rational.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you necessarily think it's untrue?

Answer (score -2):

The answer to your question is no. This is the case because the exponential of each Liouville number is transcendental. See my paper
[here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/sin-cos-exp-and-log-of-liouville-numbers/EDF4C9224998D6AB1011CB87055269B1).It is open access.

Comment: -1: not only is this a link-only answer, the paper in the link, restricted to the case of $\log_e(\text{algebraic})$, itself is a "link-only paper", referring to statements in Mahler's papers.

Comment: This answers the question completely using Mahler sets. What more could you ask?

Comment: What is the point of linking your paper when you know that all your paper says about this question is "this is a theorem by Mahler from this other paper"? At the very least link/refer to Mahler's paper(s) directly. As presumably an expert on the topic, you could also add a summary of the argument. It would make sense if your paper was included as an additional reference for related results.